# Backup of Flashdrive

Tags: usb, backup, compiling, restore

I am compiling some packages onto an external USB flash drive. Unfortunately, the compiling has not been going 100% and I often have to try redoing packages with different settings.

To make sure that things are working well, I have wanted to redo the packages again  when one fails, just in case. This of course means that I have to redo everything (which is a pain).

How do I save an exact copy of the drive and partitions so I can restore it when something goes badly wrong?

It needs to be exact (not just the files) because I have links to certain parts and partitions that I don’t want messed up.

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, the compilation probably isn't working because your flash drive probably has a FAT32 file system. It doesn't support some features that are needed for compilation. If you still want to do compilation on a flash drive for whatever reason, you can use GParted to make an ext2 partition. (Don't make an ext4; it is a journaling filesystem that will wear out your flash storage cells much faster.)

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste, I am using ext4. I did not know that it would wear it out but I cant change it now. The compilation is not working for a variety of reasons but I am fixing them as I go. I am attempting to make an LFS system if you were wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete this task, you should be able to use GNOME Disks. Install the gnome-disks package by running `sudo apt-get install gnome-disks`. After you do that, you should be able to find it somewhere in your menus. (It could be called Disk Management.) Choose the flash drive on the left side of the screen and click the gear icon at the top of the window. Choose "Create Disk Image..." and choose a place to save it. It will put it into a compressed .img file, but when restoring it back to the flash drive, you should use "Restore Disk Image..." instead of just extracting the .img file.

Comment: That sounds good! I am assuming that that will backup all partitions. Correct?

Comment: @Gabo Yes. It will back up the entire disk, including its partitioning setup and filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing the whole LFS thing, you want to learn the command line REALLY well. Here is a quick rundown of dd for you. **Beware the DD command is POWERFUL**

sdx (where x is the flash drive)
If you don't know it..

```
sudo blkid
```

also, kinda a firehose but you might like it..

```
sudo lshw
```

The first will create a file in your home directory, the second will put the file back to a flash drive.

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=~/My-LFS-Backup.iso bs=8M
sudo dd if=~/My-LFS-Backup.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

The first will create a compressed file in your home directory, the second will decompress it to the flash drive.

```
dd if=/dev/sdax bs=8M | bzip2 -9f > ~/My-LFS-Backup.bz2
sudo bunzip2 -dc ~/My-LFS-Backup.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sdx
```

The following will copy from one drive to another of equal or larger size.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy bs=8M && sync
```